# Creating a python audio player using QWebView and the HTML5 Audio API

Tags: python, webkit, html5-audio, phonon

I am seriously new to Python and my first project is quite ambitious :D

I'm trying to create an audio player using a QWebView and the HTML5 Audio API.

I want to use Phonon to actually play the media, but I'd like to be able to use the HTML5 Audio API to make an equalizer, like the one in Winamp.

I can get Phonon to play an audio file no problem, but is there a way to connect the audio output to my JavaScript so that I can play around with the different channels etc.?

Is it even the best way? I mean, would doing it this way limit the formats available to my player to those supported by WebKit, or would I still be able to play any format Phonon is able to play? (I'm assuming here, that Phonon would stream a raw/decoded version of the audio to my JavaScript, which I could then use via the Audio API)

If this isn't possible I could make a simple JavaScript wrapper around a Phonon AudioOutput object I suppose?

Any thoughts?

Comment: If you figured this out on your own, maybe post your solution as an answer?  If not, and you still need it, perhaps posting sample code would help?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't worked with the Qt framework, but peeking at the [QWebView](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qwebview.html) docs seems like there's no readily available solution to communicate with the window object.

If you want to work with a familiar protocol, then I suggest you look at the [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) microframework. It's basically a small piece of opinionated code where all the application behavior is provided by functions that receive and then return HTTP request and response objects. Here's the official [streaming documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/streaming/) so you can get an idea how building a response object looks like.

It seems you figured out how to generate the output, this would mean you'd only need to run the built-in Flask server at runtime and transport the audio data to your JavaScript client over HTTP.